# regex - remove empty lines at the end

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to remove empty quote lines at the end of a mail:

```
> Hello
> 
> thats quotet>
>
>
```

to

```
> Hello
> 
> thats quotet>
```

But the regex `preg_replace("/^>\W*$/m", "", $input_lines)` won't do the trick because it also removes the > of the empty line thats not at the end.

edit: And there is still the problem, that only > at the beginning of a line should be removed

Comment: Maybe use trim function. I hope it help

Comment: I'm sure it can be done without regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
$result = preg_replace('~^(?:^>\h*\R?)*+\z~m', '', $input_lines);
```

To avoid useless tests you can also try this more hand-driven pattern:

```
$result = preg_replace('~^(?:^>\h*\R?)*+(*SKIP)\z~m', '', $input_lines);
```

Comment: what is the sense of the `+`? And what is the sense of the "hand-driven" method? It wont work with the SKIP of course, is that a placeholder for something?

Comment: @Asara: an additional `+` after a quantifier ( `?`, `*`, `+` or `{1,5}` ) makes this last one *possessive*. This mean that the quantifier can't no more give characters back when the backtracking mechanism occurs. `(*SKIP)` isn't a placeholder, it's a *backtracking control verb*. When the backtracking occurs (when `\z` fails in our case), the regex engine will not retry all positions matched before the `(*SKIP)` and will start new tries only after *(this avoids to test useless position for nothing)*.

Comment: @Asara: it works with an without the `(*SKIP)`, you can test here: https://regex101.com/r/ikp58Q/1

Comment: @Asara: Sometimes it is useful to better control the regex engine behaviour (that is what I call "a hand-driven" pattern), but sometimes it has no effect or gives a bad result because it prevents "natural" regex engine optimizations to occur.

Answer (score 3):

Use [rtrim](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php), it removes specified characters from the right side of the string. We want to remove ">" and new line characters from the end.

**Code**:

```
echo rtrim($input, ">".PHP_EOL);
```

**Result**:

```
> Hello
> 
> thats quotet
```

Comment: Using `PHP_EOL` doesn't guarantee that the string uses the same newline sequence than PHP.

Comment: because I already unified the linebreaks, I can use this solution and prefer it because of its simplicity. But maybe you can update it with the problem casimir referenced

Comment: there is still one more problem (I updated the question already): when there is a > at the end of the last line, it must not be removed